# I try to run the FileReader function in my project and it end up with this error I do not understand:

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have to do an exercice with AJAX.  I must use a local file that I put on my PC locally and my program ask to choose this file.  The file name is "ledevoir.xml".

When I execute my program, by selecting my local file ledevoir.xml, I got this error:

> Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Here's my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <title>Exemple AJAX</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    function afficheTitres(doc) {
         titres = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
         elementol = document.createElement("ol");
         var longueur = titres.length;
         for ( k = 0; k &lt; longueur ; ++k) {
           elementli = document.createElement("li");
           elementli.appendChild(document.createTextNode(titres[k].firstChild.nodeValue));
           elementol.appendChild(elementli);
         }
         body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
         body.appendChild(elementol);
    }

    function chargeDocument(f) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(evt) {
               var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, 'application/xml');
               afficheTitres(doc);
            }
            fileReader.readAsText(f);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Récupère et affiche
      les nouvelles du devoir: </p>
    <input type="file" onchange="chargeDocument(this.files)" ></input>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't understand the error I got. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You call

`chargeDocument(this.files)`

passing the selected files, therefore the parameter `f` in `function chargeDocument(f)` is an array, not a single file. The error simply says that arrays don't have a function `readAsText`.

Instead simply only pass the first entry of the files array:

```
<input type="file" onchange="chargeDocument(this.files[0])"></input>
```